# Rating of circuit breaker for protection

Tags: protection, short-circuit, fuses, circuit-breaker, over-current

This circuit breaker is rated as 12V-48V 100A and I have to use this circuit breaker between additional alternator (24V 100A) in my vehicle and additional battery bank to provide overcurrent/short circuit protection. Will it be efficient to my 24V system or is not recommended using a 48V circuit breaker to protect my 24Vsystem.

[https://www.amazon.com/Erayco-Circuit-Trolling-12V-48VDC-Waterproof/dp/B08JQBZ985](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JQBZ985)
[image]

Comment: I don't see a datasheet, and I don't even see a manufacturer homepage by that name. Are you willing to take an Amazon listing at face value?

Comment: The listing indicates that the device is rated for 12 volt to 48 volt use - 24 volts is within that range.

Answer (score 0):

As commenters say, you need a proper datasheet for this part (ideally with certifications) to be sure it will provide the safety you seek

However, in general breakers act on current, whilst the voltage (and AC Vs DC) is primarily related to the maximum level at which they can break the circuit. As such 48V rating for 24V use should be fine.

The one area you may be concerned about is voltage drop over the unit, and whether it is too high for your app.  You'll have to do a test to be sure.